# Turning the negative values of a variable to be zero in Pyomo Model "glpk"

Tags: variables, optimization, constraints, pyomo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEmaZ.png)I have the following code in pyomo model using linear optimization "glpk"

how to modify the following code so that the discharge variable only have positive or zero values

min max functions never work neither ifs statements

def over_discharge_rule(vpp, t):
if availability_df.iloc[t,i]>0:
return getattr(vpp, f'discharge_power_{i}')[t] <= (getattr(vpp, f'capacity_{i}')[t]-DISCHARGE_LIMIT) * 2
elif availability_df.iloc[t,i]==0:
return getattr(vpp, f'discharge_power_{i}')[t] ==0

The dischargelimit is 80

I tried min,max functions and if statments as well as binary variables like flags it gives me nonlinear parameters error